# how to send keyboard signal using a shell script

Tags: shell, shell-script, x11, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard

I have an application in graphical interface that when I run it, it's not opened in full screen mode, but when I use the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> , it becomes fullscreen, I want to change the default behavior of the app to be opened in fullscreen mode.

I want to write a shell script to send this shortcut keys when I open the application, can you help me?

Comment: Is this a proprietary app or public? Name of app? If there's a command line switch that you can use to  start your app in full screen that would certainly be preferred over a script that sends key strokes to the app. Does the app have a man page or user manual?

Answer (score 3):

You can find a small tool called sendxkeys [here](https://bitbucket.org/brmtron/sendxkeys). Using this you should be able to inject key presses into your X server. After compiling it, I'm guessing that

```
./sendxkeys :0 64 37 58
```

would insert ALT+CTRL+M into your X server running on display `:0` (I may be wrong about the exact keycodes though). This can then easily be used in a script, e.g. something like:

```
/path/to/your/application & # the & is to start in background
sleep 1 # wait a short while so that the application is running
/path/to/sendxkeys :0 64 37 58 # may need other keycodes
```