# Is there a way to make a Bash script enter a certain keystroke?

Tags: bash, shell-script, tmux

Is there any way to make a `bash` script enter a certain keystroke? What I'm trying to accomplish here is a script that will run <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to exit `tmux`.

EDIT: I see that several people are saying that it's better to use a program - specific command. What if I wanted to edit a text file (in this case the bash_aliases file) using a bash script?

Comment: If you're working in X, the following may be useful: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111007/how-to-send-keyboard-signal-using-a-shell-script

Comment: If you want to edit a file in a script, use a scriptable text editor like ed/ex. If it's a separate question, start a new question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to interact with `tmux` in a script, that's where you want to use `tmux ... tmux-command`. Like:

```
tmux kill-session
```

To exit the current session.

```
tmux kill-server
```

To exit the server (kills all sessions).

```
tmux detach-client
```

to detach a client (exit, but you can reattach later).

Comment: I'm using SSH with `tmux`; when I run `tmux kill-session`, would it kill my end, or the Raspberry Pi's (what I'm SSH'ing to) end?

Comment: @evamvid, `tmux` talks to the tmux server via a unix domain socket (whose path is in `$TMUX`), so it can only talk to a tmux server on the same machine, so a process can only kill the tmux session that is running on the same machine.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [xdotool](http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/) to send keystrokes, if really necessary.

```
xdotool search "Konsole" windowactivate --sync key --clearmodifiers ctrl+b
```

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question in the title.

The way to simulate a key press in a terminal is via the TIOCSTI

For instance:

```
insert() {
  perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph";
            ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_) or
              die "$!\n" for split "", join " ", @ARGV' "$@"
}
```

However, in the case of `tmux`, if you do:

```
insert $'\02'
```

within a `tmux` pane, that will insert the `^B` character in the input buffer of the terminal of that pane, not any of the terminals attached to the current session `tmux` is reading its input from.

The solution would be to do:

```
insert $'\02' < "$(tmux lsc -F '#{client_tty}' -t '' | head -n 1)"
```

Where:

```
tmux lsc -F '#{client_tty}' -t ''
```

reports the terminal(s) attached to the running session.

But on modern Linux systems, that won't work (you'll get a *Operation not permitted* error) because, for security reasons, the TIOCSTI ioctl can only be issued to *your* controlling terminal (and the controlling terminal of a shell interpreting a script in a `tmux` pane would be the pane's terminal).

You'd have to ask `tmux` to do that, and I'm not sure that is possible.

Comment: This answer is another that pre-dated people starting to drop TIOCSTI, by three years in this case.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238232/5132

Answer (score 1):

You can easily close tmux by executing:

```
pkill -term tmux
```

This will send tmux: "Please close yourself"

Answer (score 0):

Another useful *NIX tool for automating interactions with terminal programs is Expect:

http://www.nist.gov/el/msid/expect.cfm