# How do I emulate sending keystrokes through a terminal program?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, input, input-method

I need to send keystrokes virtually to a terminal program (like *vi* or *emacs*).

I want to do something like this:

```
echo -e 'iHello, world!\e' | vi
```

and then have a *vi* session open with this buffer:

```
Hello, world!
~
~
~
~
~
```

But that does not work as *vi* does not read keystrokes through *stdin*.

I get this error:

```
ex/vi: Vi's standard input and output must be a terminal
```

How can I send some text string to a terminal program as if the string was typed directly on a keyboard?

Comment: You could use `expect` for this, as the most general case, but that's often a pain. It may be preferable to write a more specific script using shell.

Comment: `echo 'Hello, world!' | vipe` seems relevant. https://joeyh.name/code/moreutils/ or `apt install moreutils`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's typically what [`expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) was written for:

```
expect -c 'spawn -noecho vi; send "iHello World!\r\33"; interact'
```

While `expect` was written for TCL in days prior to `perl` or `python` being popular, now similar modules [for `perl`](http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod) or [`python`](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/stable/) are also available.

Another option is to issue `TIOCSTI` ioctls to your tty device to insert characters (one byte at a time) in its input queue:

```
perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph";
          ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV
         ' $'iHello World!\r\e'; vi
```

That has the benefit of avoiding an extra pseudo-terminal layer in between your terminal emulator and the application (here `vi`).

Comment: I've just found out that OpenBSD has recently removed `TIOCSTI` support due to security concerns: http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20170701132619.

Comment: @egmont, thanks. I didn't known that. It's true it can be abused across setuid/setgid, but IMO, the problem there is setuid/setgid executables, not so much the TIOCSTI ioctl (which can be very useful, you'll find many Q&A mentioning it here). The notion of changing uid whilst keeping the same environment (environ, fds, tty, limits, signal disposition, umask...) is wrong.

Comment: I agree with you that the core of the security issue lies somewhere else, and if properly addressed there, TIOCSTI should be harmless. But we also live in an imperfect world where eliminating such relatively rarely used corner case pain points does increase security. In the mean time I don't like TIOCSTI at all, I'm much more in favor of the expect-like approach. One kernel call per byte, not being able to pass a string in a single step, and not being able to use standard tools like echo or cat, doesn't sound right to me.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Stéphane Chazelas' Perl example, the following is practical from a script or command line:

```
stty -echo; perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph"; ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV ' `_cmds_` ;stty echo; _app_
```

If you drop the final *app* the output of *cmds* will be present on the input queue (as it is called in the kernel), on your current console shell or in the application that `shell`ed the command line. The `stty` just stops any (full-duplex) echo to the screen.

**Note:** technically, this is not explicitly "simulating keypress".