# force output to input (buffer) like "\033[6n" in a script

Tags: shell-script, shell, terminal, tty, c

I have tried using pipes and redirections to have (C program or scripts) output end up on the input buffer, the way `printf "\033[6n"` does, but no positive results.

Does anyone know how this is possible as:

1. a command line
2. in a shell script
3. C code

Piping output `_cmd_ > /dev/stdin` and C code `fprintf(stdin, "blah\n");` have no measurable effect.

**Note:** I don't want to "pipe" the input out to another command, I want to "inject" characters into the "keyboard buffer" (as it were).

**EDIT:** the original use case was a sandboxed cli app that allows `shell` or `system` external *commands* to interact with the OS (eg. Bas), but does *not* handle file descriptors.

Comment: I finally found the process by which the kernel outputs to input buffer (via `respond_string` in `src/drivers/tty/vt/vt.c`), but atm it is of no help. it uses a buffer to a (tty) port, but I cant decipher it.

Comment: output to fd 0 (even on another tty) does NOT put it in the "input buffer".  I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330402/dev-stdin-with-herestring), but cant find any answers either.

Comment: Look for `TIOCSTI` e.g. in `man ioctl_tty`, or https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/238232/53656, or everywhere else on the Internet. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: On a broader scale: OpenBSD has recently removed this option due to security concerns, see http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20170701132619. What's your bigger picture? Probably you should redesign the architecture of your software not to require this hack, but properly send the data to its standard input.

Comment: after much looking, deciphering and whatnot, see the end of the answer I posted, and it works from a shell or script too - bonus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Debian Bullseye, `console-tools` was absorbed into `kbd` of which `writevt` was *not* included. If you want it, the sources are linked in the update at the end of this post.

---

`writevt /dev/tty# text`, at least on Linux, maybe BSD and Unix, its currently part of the `console-tools` package. The user must have *write* privileges for the VT. Specifically, (EDIT: if its available on your OS) the full and correct answer to the OP is:

```
writevt `tty` "`_cmds_`"
```

---

This question shows the lack of depth of knowledge about base operating systems by the StackExchange community as a whole. `writevt` is very old, it is a base command installed on 99% (EDIT: Debian Linux) systems. Up until June 2002 there was no man page or maintainer for it in Debian, which may account for why a lot of people don't know about it, even though that was 15 years ago. However, even on Kali Linux (which has *everything*) it is most often not listed under *available* *commands*, even though it has been there since the start.

---

As of Debian Buster `writevt` is no longer installed by default, and according to some, may no longer even exists in any package (due to lack of Maintainer? or change in `console-tools` package?)

UPDATE: if fact I can no longer find `console-tools` on debian packages search (where I verified the contents originally), not even backports.

The original package project is here:

http://lct.sourceforge.net/

No patches are required. Raspbian/RPiOS has debian build (Wheezy to Buster) here:

http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/pool/main/c/console-tools/

Quote from Yan Dirson:

> Current (public) software projects I work on The Debian GNU/Linux project, of which I'm a member since 1997.

http://ydirson.free.fr/en/software/

[waiting for `kbd` absorb - 2001](http://web.archive.org/web/20011229201301/http://ydirson.free.fr/en/software/)

The `console-tools` package from the "Linux Console Tools" project is still available in RPiOS. It is not the same as `linuxconsoletools` package from the "Linux Console Project" project, which is also on SourceForge.

Comment: I have no idea from where you're getting your (lack of) knowledge, but **writevt** is not installed on 99% of Linux systems.
I've just installed "Everything" from [Fedora Core 2](https://archive.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/core/2/i386/iso/) (released in 2004) and guess what? The command was not available.
Fedora 36 (2022) also does not have it.
Same goes for a RHEL 6 clone (released in 2012 IIRC).
Should I also mention that not even [Ubuntu 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=writevt&mode=&suite=bionic&arch=any) has it?

Comment: Note: That post was 5 years ago. `console-tools` and particularly the setting console fonts change 2x from Jessie to Buster. At the time I also checked Devuan - `writevt` is even in SpareMiNT which is RedHat RPM based

Answer (score 2):

**Edit:** The short answer *was* `/dev/uinput`, now its `TIOCSTI` (see end of post)

---

This is the answer so far, and to address the comments:

[`ioctl_tty(2)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ioctl_tty.2.html) I dont have, but a lookup of `TIOCSTI` on the kernel source (via [FreeElectrons](https://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v4.14.1/ident/TIOCSTI) ) will show `tiocsti` "fake input character", which uses a `tty_struct` context.

The application in question is running all the time, interactively, so pipes and redirects cant be used. It can `shell` out for scripting, however, unlike a lot of other similar apps, it does not, nor allows for, capture the results, only allowing `stdin` & `stdout` to do their thing as per normal.

For the foreseeable future there is no chance of changing this, its not my application. However I was able to cut the results of `"\033[6n"`, which have been injected into the keyboard buffer by the kernel through `tty_insert_flip_char` & `tty_schedule_flip` in `src/drivers/tty/tty_buffer.c`, which uses a `tty_port` context.

If memory serves, before the FD file structure was changed, when there was *only* 4 file descriptors, it may have been possible to achieve this. Nowadays although you can write to `/dev/stdin` or `/proc/self/fd/0`, they are connected to `/dev/tty#` and anything written to to a TTY device will end up on the screen (`/dev/stdout`). The kernel seems to bypass the file descriptor route when using TTY's, notice the `flip` functions refer to it as a *port*.

Any userland app does not have access to either of those kernel functions. Under X-Windows it is possible to use `xvkbd` and `xdotool` or `xte`, but this app is being used on the linux (VT) console.

---

**The (Almost) Real Answer:**

Although `/dev/uinput` does not have user privileges (on most systems), `sudo` a script that `printf` all arguments will work.

Alternatively, the keyboard *event* will also work, as all users have access to it, but it changes per boot and per system (mine is normally `/dev/input/event0`, but not always).

After further research, neither of these approaches is practical, especially for scripting. The thing we need to understand about what needs to be done, is that we just want to present *text* on the input buffer, not "simulate a keypress" (which is how the above devices work).

---

**The (Most Practical) Real Answer:**

An offsite question referred back to an answer on stackexchange, from 2011 ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7370538/ask-a-running-bash-interactive-to-run-a-command-from-outside/7370822#7370822)). It uses `TIOCSTI`. After reviewing the the Perl example again, it may also be practical for scripting, where an application is not supplied.

```
perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph";
      ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV
     ' `_cmds_`
```

However it does echo it to the screen as well. After many hours of further research and experimentation the following is practical in a script or on the command line:

```
stty -echo; perl -le 'require "sys/ioctl.ph"; ioctl(STDIN, &TIOCSTI, $_) for split "", join " ", @ARGV ' `_cmds_` ;stty echo
```

**Note:** although `TIOCSTI` was revoked in [OpenBSD 6.2](https://www.openbsd.org/62.html) (Oct 2017), apparently the Linux Kernel developers are of the *opposite* mind, categorically refusing to revoke it (you can read more about this in the [OpenBSD Journal](http://undeadly.org/cgi?action=article&sid=20170701132619)).

Comment: Since [Linux v2.6.12](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/drivers/char/tty_io.c?h=v2.6.12#n1990) if not earlier, there's this code `if ((current->signal->tty != tty) && !capable(CAP_SYS_ADMIN)) return -EPERM` in the `tiocsti` function.
It looks to me like if you're trying to control a different TTY and you don't have CAP_SYS_ADMIN, you'll get an error. It doesn't matter if the TTY is yours.
So for example if you have two tabs in GNOME terminal and you start a program in the first one, you won't be able to control it from the second tab, unless you're root.

Comment: I tested that _at the time_ in Devuan and Raspbian, and both worked. I also checked the source, due to the BSD "fix", so maybe there is a compile time Define - note `writevt` _requires_ user permissions, but the above does not

Comment: @CristianCiupitu you obviously didn't read _everything_ otherwise you would have seen _After further research, neither of these approaches is practical, especially for scripting. The thing we need to understand about what needs to be done, is that we just want to present text on the input buffer, not "simulate a keypress"_ - BTW I update the next post too