# iTerm2 inyecting text into the console

Tags: iterm2

I'm using iTerm2 in a MacOS Sierra. I'd like to have the ability to inject some text into the console (like for executing a string of commands).

Ideally, I could have a local file

```
# local.txt
echo Hello World
```

I would like to make iTerm2 type those characters in my console window tab.

I've reviewed iTerm2 documentation and only found the Triggers option (less than optimal), and the Scripts which have to be written in AppleScript and is therefore an unnecesary hassle.

I just want to make iTerm2 type the contents of a text file automatically into the console (like a "macro" script).

Is this possible? How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the TIOCSTI ioctl (as `root`) for example [with `ttywrite`](https://github.com/thrig/scripts/blob/master/tty/ttywrite.c) one could inject commands

```
% echo echo hello world > local
% sudo ttywrite $(tty) < local
echo hello world
% echo hello world
hello world
%
```

Though presumably you would target some other TTY instead of the current one (or possibly turn off echo with `stty`...)

Comment: Three quarters of a year before this answer was written, people started to drop TIOCSTI.  Whether this trend will reach Apple remains to be seen.  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/406690/5132

Answer (score 0):

You can check my answer [here](https://superuser.com/a/1347560).

Since I'm using iTerm2, I came up with:

You can also have a script like `~/test.py`

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

print("echo hello world")
```

And then execute this script as a co-process in iTerm2 menu Session->Run Co-Process, and specifying the script as `~/test.py`.

Happy coding!