# configure and install tmux plugins automatically

Tags: bash, terminal, tmux

I'm trying to write a bash script which will setup my tmux environment automatically. Essentially what I need to do is:

1. Copy .tmux.conf from my repo
2. Clone https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm into ~/.tmux/plugins/tpm
3. Run tmux
4. Execute `<Prefix>-I` in the tmux session (for me prefix is Ctrl-B)

Steps 1-3 are quite simple, but I don't know how to send a key sequence in bash to a terminal.

**EDIT**

I tried running the following command:
`tmux send-prefix -t 0; tmux send-keys -t 0 "I`

but it didn't work. I got a following error:
`I: command not found`
.Any ideas on how to make it work?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111957/is-there-a-way-to-make-a-bash-script-enter-a-certain-keystroke

Comment: Run [the script to update the plugins](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm/blob/master/scripts/update_plugin.sh) directly, instead of trying to inject the keystoke?

Comment: @AlexStragies Thanks. Didn't know one was available.

Comment: @AlexStragies Write up an answer. I will accept and upvote it so we could close this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The action #4 in your list (`"Execute <Prefix>-I in the tmux session"`) is setup by [`tpm`](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm) to run one of the scripts([update_plugin.sh](https://github.com/tmux-plugins/tpm/blob/master/scripts/update_plugin.sh)) installed by `tpm`.

As such, you can just just call this script as part of your deployment script, instead of trying to inject the keystroke to trigger it.