# Bring up shutdown menu of Cinnamon via command line

Tags: command-line, shutdown, cinnamon

How can I bring up the shutdown menu of [Cinnamon](http://cinnamon.linuxmint.com/) via command line?

**Note**: I don't want the user menu. This menu for switching or logging out a user is brought up via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd>.

Comment: Using the tool described in http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/111007/how-to-send-keyboard-signal-using-a-shell-script/ you should be able to mimic a ctrl-alt-del keypress

Comment: @brm That's the point: I *don't* want the _Ctrl+Alt+Del_ window, since it only shows user related actions like logging off or switching.

Comment: What's wrong with `sudo shutdown now`?

Comment: @MikeWaters Sometimes you want to be able to pick between shutdown and suspend, for example.

Answer (score 6):

I am using Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.2, Rafaela. I have my own keyboard shortcut assigned for the shutdown menu. The keyboard shortcut works perfectly fine on this version. It is the same command as the other answer. The man page for `cinnamon-session-quit` also has some other options such as `--logout` for the logout menu.

```
cinnamon-session-quit --power-off
```

Answer (score 2):

yep, but

```
cinnamon-session-quit --power-off
```

works only from terminal an not from shortcuts (this is still uncertain since I didn't reboot yet)

Comment: You can use every command as shortcut.
You may however need to run it as a shell argument.
For example: bash -c 'cinnamon-session-quit --power-off'
This will evoke the command just as it would be evoked inside a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

I am currently using Linux Mint Debian Edition (LMDE) 2 and I can confirm that

```
cinnamon-session-quit --power-off
```

can be used as a command in custom shortcuts (System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcut -> Custom Shortcuts).

But it should be easier to set the "Shut Down" shortcut (in System Settings -> Keyboard -> Shortcut -> System -> Shut Down)...